# Runtime Error 9 when using "With Sheet"

Tags: excel, vba

I came up with a solution that should circumvent my original issue (found below VBA code so I can keep this short and sweet if extra info is unnecessary) but I get a runtime error9. I tested this code on two basic workbooks and it worked fine. The LastRow line is the line that highlights when debugging. I tried to surround the file name in single 's since the name has spaces but that didn't resolve the error.

```
Sub MakeGSATable()

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Workbooks("Reservation Activity Dashboard (RAD) CP.xlsm").Worksheets("GSR").Cells(Worksheets("GSR").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

With Workbooks("Reservation Activity Dashboard (RAD) CP.xlsm").Worksheets("GSR")
.Range("A8").Select
.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$8:$AA$" & LastRow), , xlYes).Name = _
    "GSATable"
.ListObjects("GSATable").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight20"
End With

End Sub
```

As background: my main workbook has several macros and must be opened and kept in full screen and without the formula bar. I added a macro for workbook activate/deactivating so if users open another instance of Excel, it will work normally. One of the macros in my main book would pull up another workbook, fire the macros I need within it but at some point it gets caught up in the activate/deactivate macro, never actually finishing the macros that otherwise work without the activate/deactivate macro. So I decided to try and add this macro as I think it will be a good workaround.

Comment: There is probably no `Worksheets("GSR")` in `ActiveWorkbook`, so you probably need to use `Workbooks("Reservation Activity Dashboard (RAD) CP.xlsm").Worksheets("GSR")` instead (when calculating `.Rows.Count`)

Comment: I guess this is handy to always write this long-winded string `Workbooks("Reservation Activity Dashboard (RAD) CP.xlsm")`

Comment: Usin `Selection` and `GSR` worksheet. H-m-m-m... What could go wrong?

Comment: ^^ All the `Select` statements will crash if "GSR" isn't the active worksheet but, as far as I can see, they are all redundant anyway and should therefore be deleted.  But you should change `Range("$A$8:$AA$" & LastRow)` to be `.Range("$A$8:$AA$" & LastRow)`.

Comment: Not everyone coming to ask a question here is an expert, @JohnyL. Your smart-aleck comments, esp re: "Selection" don't help anyone so thanks for nothing. I used the recorder to arrive at this and modified it as best I could. And my long-winded strings are to help me understand what's going on as I'm still pretty new to VBA with no actual class on it. When a file works as it should, I then go back and add variables for a smaller packaged code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment your line

```
LastRow = Workbooks("Reservation Activity Dashboard (RAD) CP.xlsm").Worksheets("GSR").Cells(Worksheets("GSR").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

is equivalent to

```
LastRow = Workbooks("Reservation Activity Dashboard (RAD) CP.xlsm").Worksheets("GSR").Cells(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("GSR").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

so, if there is no "GSR" worksheet in the active workbook, it will give a "subscript out of range" error.

The line should actually say

```
LastRow = Workbooks("Reservation Activity Dashboard (RAD) CP.xlsm").Worksheets("GSR").Cells(Workbooks("Reservation Activity Dashboard (RAD) CP.xlsm").Worksheets("GSR").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

but that is getting a bit unwieldy, so it would be better if you moved it inside your `With` block:

```
With Workbooks("Reservation Activity Dashboard (RAD) CP.xlsm").Worksheets("GSR")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    '...
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining the top portion as I did modify it some and took out the activesheet parts as the main book wasn't the active sheet in my code and thought I could just change it to whatever open book I wanted. I applied your changes and got an error 1004 at the .Range("A8") line. I went ahead and marked the main workbook to activate at the top of the MakeGSRTable and this got it to work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Craig As I said in a comment to the question, the `Select` statements all seem redundant - just delete them.

Comment: You're too good, Yow! I removed the selection parts, added the "." before the Range("$A$8:$AA$" & LastRow) line, removed my newest activate line, and it runs smoothly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Write the `lastRow` call in a `With block` as well to fully qualify all objects as desired.

```
Dim LastRow As Long
With Workbooks("Reservation Activity Dashboard (RAD) CP.xlsm").Worksheets("GSR")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
```